# PC freezes when entering automatic repair, then power off

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, bootable-media

Today, I’ve been upgrading my RAM and CPU. Due to some confusion, I powered off the PC during boot, which I believe has led to hard drive problems. The drive is recognised as bootable in my BIOS, but booting to it brings up the ‘Automatic repair’ screen. The wheel will spin for a few seconds, then the animation will freeze and my fans will spin up. It will then either power off after 1 minute, or continue like this. Occasionally it goes to a ‘MACHINE_CHECK_ERROR’ BSOD.

I’ve tried booting from a Windows setup USB, but it seems to ignore this and continue attempting to boot from the drive.

Mobo: ASUS PRIME H310M-K
RAM: Corsair Vengeance LPX 2x16GB 2666
CPU: i7-9700F

My drive is an SSD

Edit: Solved, check my answer

Comment: Please indicate the specific CPU you are upgrading from.  You should also indicate what version of Windows 10 you have installed.

Comment: I am upgrading from an i3-8100k, and I am unable to check my version number, although I’m using Professional.

Comment: I suspect this is due to the fact your replacement processor doesn’t have an Intel GPU.  You will have to put the old processor in order to uninstall the Intel display drivers and disable the iGPU within the firmware at a minimum

Comment: It does not have integrated graphics, which is why I’m connecting using my 1050Ti. I have also reset the CMOS several times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the CPU was not supported by the BIOS. Flashing the latest update fixed the issue